# Paquet Portmap Install

Tags: 12.04

On this machine, i have already install portmap it:

```
 apt-get install portmap
```

it works well

But, i need to install it on another machine where i don't have internet

i have to download the paquet ? How can i do please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download Portmap: http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/net/portmap

ES 64: http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/portmap/portmap_6.0.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb

ES i386: http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/portmap/portmap_6.0.0-1ubuntu2_i386.deb

Copy this package to your machine where you want to install it..

CTRL + ALT + T (Open Terminal)

go to folder where you put in one of these packages:
$ cd desktop

Then install it:

```
dpkg -i portmap_6.0.0-1ubuntu2_i386.deb
```